# Average amplitude and DC component

Tags: dc, signal, wave, amplitude

While I read my college book in signals, I got stuck with some basics:

> DC component is component of zero frequency. With no DC component, a signal has an average amplitude of zero, with a DC component it has frequency term at f = 0 and a nonzero average amplitude.

- What is the benefit of having an average amplitude equal to zero?
- What are the pros and cons when a signal has a DC component so the amplitude get zero or has not so get non zero?

Comment: Some signals do have DC levels; some don't. Some circuits need DC levels; some don't. There are no pros and cons because it's like asking what are the pros and cons for using wheels on a motor car compared to a hovercraft. Some things need wheels period; some things can't have wheels period; some things can work with or without wheels.

Comment: @Andyaka I think that's an answer candidate.

Comment: You are thinking in advantages and disadvantages but this isn't about advantages and disadvantages. It is about **describing a signal**. Like Andy comments: some things have wheels, some don't. Another example: some plants are edible, some are not. Some people like cheese, others don't. These are no pros/cons, they're just describing what it is.

Comment: thanks all i just got confused , and i thought there some foundation i was should to know to get these concepts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two examples:

Suppose you send a signal with a DC component to a loudspeaker. The cone of the loudspeaker wouldn't then move around its center position, as it is designed to do, but be pushed out constantly by the DC component.

It will move around that pushed-out position to play music, but not moving around its center position will give distortion. The average amplitude should be zero, so this is a case where you *don't* want a DC component in your signal.

Suppose you want to sample a signal with an average amplitude of zero.

Unfortunately, most ADCs can't sample negative voltages, so you will have to lift the whole signal far enough for it to stay above 0 V all the time.

This means you will have to add a DC offset, so that the ADC can sample the signal. This is a case where you *do* want a signal with a DC component.

There are no general pros and cons to having a DC offset; it all depends on the circuit handling the signal and the purpose of the signal: sometimes you want or need a DC component, sometimes you don't.

The terminology is just there to describe the signal; it is not a value judgment.

Comment: thanks ocrdu , you help me a lot